# Get paid non paid clients Mysql Joins

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to create a query that will take information out of 3 tables for a booking system that I am creating.

i need to find the records that are older than 30 minutes, and client id exists in payment table

I have the following tables:

**Table booking**

```
id
date
...
```

**Table client**

```
id
booking_id
date_time
...
```

**Table payments**

```
id
client_id
booking_id
...
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM client c
LEFT JOIN payments p 
ON c.id = p.client_id 
AND p.id = NULL
AND c.date_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
JOIN booking b on c.booking_id = b.id
```

The only problem it also include paid client that i don't want , please help me solve the problem.

i just needed Left join so that i can get those entries which are not included on table payments , my app actually add entry in payments table once user pay via paypal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, you seem to only want `join`s between the tables.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM client c JOIN
     booking b
     on c.booking_id = b.id JOIN
     payments p 
     ON c.id = p.client_id AND c.date_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon for helping , just needed little bit help more, 
i just needed Left join so that i can get those entries which are not included in table payments , my app actually add entry in payments table once user pay via paypal.